# Custom error response for API endpoints in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I want to create custom responses on errors like 404 & 500 on my Next.js application. I am aware that you can create custom error pages in the `/pages` directory, but for my `pages/api` endpoints I want the errors to be of JSON format and I'm pretty sure that's not possible in the `/pages` directory - It throws me an error when I return JSON there as it wants a React component.

Can anyone help me out on how to do this?

Comment: So you want to throw json errors on your api endpoints or in your pages?

Comment: can nextJS api catch 404? i know you can't catch 500. Make a `try/catch` block and see. I know for your own error, you can output any type of error you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before in the NextJS API layer.

```
  let res1, res2, res3;
  try {
    res1 = await getIdentity(authToken, user.id);
    const username = (res1 as { userName: string }).userName;
    res2 = await postIdentity(authToken, username, user.password);
    res3 = await putIdentity(authToken, user.id, username, user.newPassword);
  } catch (e) {
    // refine your own error here if needed
    return res.status(200).json(e);
  }
```

You can see all `getIdentity`, `postIdentity` and `putIdentity` are api calls which can generate anything from 200 to 405. And in case I catch anything I return 200 with my own error handling code.